# Python: How to extract the last 3 digits of each object in my list full of integers?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of integers. Each integer has 6 digits.
For example:

```
ids = [335381, 779097, 147786, 951524]
```

I want to make a new list that only contains the last 3 digits for each of these ids, the output should look like this:

```
new_ids = [381, 097, 786, 524]
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last three digits are the remainder after dividing by 1000.

```
new_ids = [x % 1000 for x in ids]
```

If you specifically want `097`, you'll have to use strings.

```
# Convert the result to a zero-padded string
new_ids = [f'{x%1000:03}' for x in ids]  # Pad the remainder with 0s
```

or

```
# Convert to a string of at least 3 digits, then take the last 3
new_ids = [f'{x:03}'[-3:] for x in ids]
```

Comment: For those wondering about the `f` syntax: [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings).

Answer (score 2):

Very efficient answers have been given. These are just two other methods that can be used - user case depending: **slicing** and **regex**.

#### Simple Slicing:

```
[int(str(i)[-3:]) for i in ids]

>>> [381, 97, 786, 524]
```

#### Regex:

```
import re

exp = re.compile('(\d{3})$')
[int(exp.findall(str(i))[0]) for i in ids]

>>> [381, 97, 786, 524]
```

Comment: Hi @Anne - My pleasure, glad it’s helped you.  Would you mind accepting the answer please?  (It’s the little green tick mark).  Thanks!

Comment: Your slicing solution is a non-sense, you do a double-conversoion and a slicing, while the modulo operator does all 3 in 1, 6 times faster, and the regex solution is twice slower as your slicing. Dealing with number is **so** much better that passing to string. There is an existing operator, don't try a strange solution that ends same

Comment: @azro - Yes.  I agree with your sentiment.  For this reason I started the answer with “Very efficient answers have been given.”  These are just additional (less-efficient) methods.  Therefore, whoever downvoted was unnecessary.  In fact, I thought using modulo was quite clever, nice answer.

Comment: The modulo answer isn't "very efficient", it's *normal*. Yours are *very inefficient*. And complicated. No idea why anyone would upvote or accept this.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

You may do modulo 1000:

```
ids = [335381, 779097, 147786, 951524]
ids = [i%1000 for i in ids]            # [381, 97, 786, 524]
```

---

#### Note

Note that `097` as digit is not a valid representation, `97` is right, to see it as 3 digits with a 0-leading you need a string representation

---

#### Bench

As there is multiple answer, I'm adding a little `timeit` scores

```
import timeit

r = timeit.timeit("[i%1000 for i in ids]", setup="ids = [335381, 779097, 147786, 951524]")
print(str(round(r, 2)) + 'µs, per iteration')

r = timeit.timeit("[int(str(i)[-3:]) for i in ids]", setup="ids = [335381, 779097, 147786, 951524]")
print(str(round(r, 2)) + 'µs, per iteration')

r = timeit.timeit("[int(exp.findall(str(i))[0]) for i in ids]",
                  setup=r"ids = [335381, 779097, 147786, 951524];import re;exp = re.compile('(\d{3})$')")
print(str(round(r, 2)) + 'µs, per iteration')
```

Results

```
0.75µs, per iteration     
5.5µs, per iteration     # modulo is about  6 times faster
12.86µs, per iteration   # modulo is about 15 times faster
```

Comment: appreciate the quick response and simplicity of it.

Comment: @Anne You're welcome. You can think about accepting an answer now. To help you decide I've add a benchmark of mine and the other solution at the end of my post, to help you decide